# Cannot find symbol Double.parseDouble(args[0])

Tags: java

Whenever I try to run the following code Java tells me it cannot find symbol.

```
public class Quadratic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double b = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double c = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        double discriminant = b * b - 4.0 * c;
        double d = Math.sqrt(discriminant);
        System.out.println((-b + d) / 2.0);
        System.out.println((-b - d) / 2.0);
    }
}
```

I *think* it worked last week. Why do I keep getting this error?

Comment: Which line is it complaining about?

Comment: We need the args array content, i.e. the command line arguments.

Comment: You might be missing an import statement in your code.

Comment: Show us `step by step` when you run this program.

Comment: The `parseDouble` method was added to Java in version 1.2. Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: Please five full stack trace

Answer (score 2):

When you think, it worked last week, you should recall what you did within that week which could break your existing code.

I suppose you have created a new class named `Double`. Without it, java automatically imports `java.lang.Double`if you use `Double`, but if you have a class with the same short name within your package, that class is preferred. And that class does not have the method `parseDouble`.

So you can do either, refer explicitly to `java.lang.Double` instead of just `Double` or remove the new `Double` class from your package.

But that’s just a guess. There’s too little information about your environment.